# DataGridView make row headers unable to select

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview on C# and when I click on a **row header**, it selects the row and the header.

[image]

And what I want is when user click the row header on the left. It must select whole row **except** the header itself, while header still functional. Just like this :
[image]

I don't want to change visibility of row headers to false. I don't want to select row headers values since this gridview will be use for copying data to excel in a correct format. (not export, just copy & paste)

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

And set `dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle` same as `dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle`

Comment: It still selects the Row header. I don't want it to select the row header.

Comment: @Ozan Ayten try `dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect` ... but it has certain restriction .. please try this and reply back

Comment: Still no. I think approach should be different. Something like dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick { Select whole row but not header itself } but I don't know how to put those statement in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `RowHeadersVisible` property of `DataGridView` to `false` .

Try This:

```
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

Comment: As I stated on my question, I don't want row headers are unvisible.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick (object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;

        foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells)
        {
            cell.Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

(If this is excaclty what you need, try to ACCEPT the answer.)

Comment: It isn't what I want tho. It does the job for one cell. Also looses functionability after first header click. But idea is seems O.K I'll try to improve.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle` 
set the `SelectionBackColor` the same as `BackColor`
set the `SelectionForeColor` the same as `ForeColor`